Update field in a DO SET UPDATE from a query result value
I have the following query:
INSERT INTO table1 (
  col1,
  col2,
  col3
)
VALUES (
  %s,
  (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE name = %s),
  %s,
)
ON CONFLICT (fk_id)
DO UPDATE SET
  col1 = %s,
  ***col2 = (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE name = %s),***
  col3 = %s
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE fk_id = %s
)
RETURNING id;

The one in bold/italic asterisks causes a "String literal error". But when it's removed, the query works fine. Is there any possible way to get the value from another table inside a DO SET UPDATE clause?

are you sure this is python code?

I'm going to say it is due to whatever argument you are passing into the %s parameter in name = %s. You need to include the entire code example in your question text, with the arguments and their values.

You do not need to get the value during the on conflict do update .... phase. You already have them. When Postgres detects the conflict it creates a image on the insert row which you access as excluded. So otherwise leaving the statement exactly as is, it becomes:
INSERT INTO table1 (
  col1,
  col2,
  col3
)
VALUES (
  %s,
  (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE name = %s),
  %s,
)
ON CONFLICT (fk_id)
DO UPDATE SET
  col1 = excluded.col1
  col2 = excluded.col2
  col3 = excluded.col3
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE fk_id = %s
)
RETURNING id;

